# Is there a difference between `po $arg1` and `bt` in a breakpoint debugger command?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, crash-reports

I'm wondering if there is a difference between what you get in the debugger when you set the exception breakpoint debugger command to:

> po $arg1

vs

> bt

If so, can you explain to me what those differences are, and maybe which one is more beneficial (and if benefit is situational, in what situation(s))?

I've seen both suggested in tutorials, but I'm not sure which one is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`bt` is a slightly fancy lldb shortcut for `thread backtrace`.  `bt` will show you the sequence of calls that got you to the breakpoint.  If any of the calling functions on the stack have debug information, lldb will also print the arguments to the function.  This is the most generally useful thing to do when you hit a breakpoint since it answers the more general "where am I" question.

`po $arg1` is a much more specialized thing.

`$arg1` is lldb's shorthand for the register used to pass the first argument to a function.  If you are on the first instruction of a function, then this register will hold the value that was passed in when the function was called.  Note, however, `$arg1` is really just a register name so if that register gets reused - for instance when the function you are stopped in calls another function the incoming argument value will get overwritten.  So `$arg1` only means "first argument" if you are stopped at the very beginning of the function.

`po` is short hand for `expr -O --`.  It evaluates the expression it is passed and then if the result is an ObjC or Swift object, it calls into the runtime to retrieve the custom description of the object and prints that.  Otherwise it prints the value.

So `po $arg1` prints the object description for the first argument to a function IF you are stopped at the beginning of the function.  The most common use of this is that all ObjC methods take the `self` parameter as the first argument.  So if you stop at the beginning of a method, `po $arg1` will print the object description of the `self` parameter.